# Let $u\in C^{1, \alpha}$. Why $\int |u(x)|>+\infty?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $u\in C^{1, \alpha}$, in particular $u$ is uniformly continuous.
Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n\to +\infty$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ be fixed. Assume that
$$|u(x_n)|>\varepsilon \quad\forall n.$$

By using the uniform continuity one can find a radius $r>0$ such that for each $B_r(x_n)$ one has
$$|u(x_n)|>\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \quad \forall x\in B_r(x_n).$$

Anyone could help me to understand why it implies that $$\int |u(x)|>+\infty?$$

I would say that
$$\int |u(x)| dx>\sum_n\int_{B_n} |u(x)| dx$$
but I do not know how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track; to finish the proof merely note that $$\int|u| \geq \sum_n\int_{B_n}|u| \geq \sum_n 2r\varepsilon  = +\infty,$$ where $2r = \mu(B_n)$ is the measure of the 1-dimensional ball of radius $r$.

Comment: thank you fo the answer. How it changes if you are setted in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$ instead?

Comment: The answer is almost completely the same. Instead you will arrive at the lower bound $$\sum_k \mu(B_k)\varepsilon,$$ where $\mu(B_k)$ is the volume of $B_k$. Since $B_k$ is just a ball of radius $r$, it holds $\mu(B_k)$ is a fixed constant for all $k\geq 1$, hence $\sum_k \mu(B_k) \varepsilon = \infty$.